# Contain function in SET check only first element not all the element

Tags: apex, list, set

I am not getting why It is not giving me the correct output. If i Test **0011b00000sXK8mAAG** id then result is **YES** or if i test any id from (**0011b00000sXKBgAAO / 0011b00000sXKgDAAW** ) then it gives me **No** output.  i am not getting what is the problem. and how can i fix that issue.

Note: String myid can be dynamic. Here  i just use ids for testing purpose .

```java
string myid = '0011b00000sXK8mAAG, 0011b00000sXKBgAAO, 0011b00000sXKgDAAW,';
Set<string> abc = new set<string>();
abc.addall(myid.split(','));
system.debug('string: ' + myid);
system.debug('set: ' + abc);

if(abc.contains('0011b00000sXKBgAAO')){
    system.debug('Yes');
}
else{
    system.debug('No');
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your starting string (`0011b00000sXK8mAAG, 0011b00000sXKBgAAO, 0011b00000sXKgDAAW,`) contains two space characters.

If you split the string on the commas, there is a preceding space character that gets included in the second ( `0011b00000sXKBgAAO`) and third ( `0011b00000sXKgDAAW`) elements in your list. You will see the spaces if you run the following:

```java
String t = '0011b00000sXK8mAAG, 0011b00000sXKBgAAO, 0011b00000sXKgDAAW,';
System.debug(t);

Set<String> setOfStrings = new Set<String>(t.split(','));
System.debug(setOfStrings);

for(String s : setOfStrings) {
    System.debug(s);
}
```

You will need to either 1) start with a string that has no white-space, 2) strip out the white-space characters, or 3) use `String.split(', ')` with a space so the comma and space as a pair are treated as the string to split on.

My recommendation, if your source string should always be a comma-delimited list of IDs, is to use `deleteWhitespace` like so: `myString = myString.deleteWhitespace()`. That will remove all whitespace characters from your string.

Comment: Thank you so much, Great.

Comment: Also: Ids should be stored in a `Set<Id>`, not a `Set<String>`. Strings don't know that 15-char == 18-char Id, and don't validate for legal Ids.